# How do I get the image from a imageicon in a jlabel or jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to use the draw method and I need to get Image from the jlabel or jbutton but don't know how to exactly do this, anyone know how?
Something like this for example

```
g.drawImage(tiles[(bounds[0]+j)%Map.width][i].getIcon().getImage(), 0, 0, null);
```

but this obviously doesn't work
with tiles[(bounds[0]+j)%Map.width][i] being a jlabel

Comment: What about imageIcon.getImage()?

Comment: I figured a way by just calling it in a different instance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a working `ImageIcon`, and you only need to include it in your `JLabel` (as stated in the title of the question).

As explained in the [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) tutorial, you can create labels with an image and text, text only or image only.
For the latter, use the [`new JLabel( icon )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel%28javax.swing.Icon%29) constructor

Comment: This is not what I'm asking sorry for it be not being too clear for example g.drawImage(tiles[(bounds[0]+j)%Map.width][i].getIcon().getImage(), 0, 0, null); but this obviously doesn't work